# MAUI HorizontalStackLayout has no effect

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to do a little MAUI project on my own and it appears the HorizontalStackLayout has no effects on the childs controls.

Here the xaml code:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Game">
                    <Border HeightRequest="100"
                            Stroke="Gray"
                            BackgroundColor="GhostWhite"
                            StrokeThickness="3"
                            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   Margin="10, 0, 0, 10"/>
                            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ConsolesList}"
                                            x:Name="ListConsole">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Console">
                                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                       TextColor="Black"
                                                       Margin="10, 0, 0, 10"/>
                                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Border.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:MainViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                                                  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Border.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

And here the result:
[image]

As you can see, the names of the consoles from the second label are positioned vertically instead of horizontally.

I tried to remove the horizontalStackLayout and change the VerticalStackLayout into an horizontal one but even then, nothing changes.
I also tried to change the two by Horizontal and vertical stack layout with a normal stackLayout and giving the Orientation the vertical for the first and horizontal for the second, still nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/6.0/UserInterface/Views/CollectionViewDemos/CollectionViewDemos/Views/Layout/HorizontalListPage.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your entire `DataTemplate`

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Console">
  <HorizontalStackLayout>
     <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" Margin="10, 0, 0, 10"/>
  </HorizontalStackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

is repeated **once** for each item in `ItemsSource`.  That means that your UI contains one `HorizontalStackLayout` for each console

`CollectionView` has an `ItemsLayout` property that can be set to `HorizontalList` to layout items within the template **Horizontally** instead of the default **Vertical** layout

Comment: Thank you a lot! I was so focused on the why the the HorizontalStackLayout wasn't working that I forgot to check others control properties.